# List comprehension to find if it's weekend on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to write as list comprehension the following code:

```
is_weekend = list()
for i in df['date']:
 if i.weekday() > 4:
   is_weekend.append(1)
 else:
   is_weekend.append(0)
```

I've already tried

```
is_weekend = [i == 1 for i in df['date'] if i.weekday() > 4 else i == 0]
```

But it throws invalid syntax errors.

Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
is_weekend = [1 if i.weekday() > 4 else 0 for i in df['date']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will cast the boolean into 1 or 0 but it is iterative

```
is_weekend = [int(i.weekday() > 4) for i in df['date']]
```

A better way would be to use a lambda with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on the `date` column and convert the resulting series into list using the [tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method.

```
is_weekend = df['date'].apply(lambda i: 1 if i.weekday() > 4 else 0).tolist()
```